# Extracting multiple pieces of text from multiple web pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest

The first part of this code (up to "pages") successfully retrieves the pages from which I want to scrape.  I'm then struggling to find a way to extract pieces of article text, with the associated dates, as a data frame.

I get:

*Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"*

Any guidance on elegance, clarity and efficiency also welcome as this is personal learning.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)

llply(1:2, function(i) {

  read_html(str_c("http://www.thetimes.co.uk/search?p=", i, "&q=tech")) %>% 
    html_nodes(".Headline--regular a") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>%
    url_absolute("http://www.thetimes.co.uk")

}) -> links

pages <- links %>% unlist() %>% map(read_html)

map_df(pages, function(x) {

  text = read_html(x) %>% 
    html_nodes(".Article-content p") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    str_extract(".+skills.+")

  date = read_html(x) %>% 
    html_nodes(".Dateline") %>% 
    html_text()

}) -> article_df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice, you were nearly there! There are two mistakes here:

1. The variable `pages` already contains the parsed html code. Therefore, applying `read_html` again on a single page (i.e. inside `map_df`) doesn't work. This is the error message you get.
2. The function inside map_df isn't correct. As there is no explicit return the last calculated value is returned, that is `date`. The variable `text` is completely forgotten. You have to pack these two variables inside a data frame.

The following contains the fixed code.

```
article_df <- map_df(pages, function(x) {
  data_frame(
    text = x %>% 
      html_nodes(".Article-content p") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      str_extract(".+skills.+"),

    date = x %>% 
      html_nodes(".Dateline") %>% 
      html_text()
  )
})
```

Also a few comments on the code itself:

- I think it is better to use `<-` instead of `->`. This way one can more easily find where the variable is assigned and if one uses 'speaking variable names' it is much easier to understand the code.
- I'd prefer using the package `purrr` instead of `plyr`. `purrr` is part of the `tidyverse` package. So, instead of the function `llply` you could simply use `map`. There is a [nice article](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/bk01_base-functions.html) on `purrr` vs `plyr`.

```
links <- map(1:2, function(i) {
  read_html(str_c("http://www.thetimes.co.uk/search?p=", i, "&q=tech")) %>% 
    html_nodes(".Headline--regular a") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>%
    url_absolute("http://www.thetimes.co.uk")
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  Really appreciate the tips as well as the fix.  Are there any pros/cons of tibble versus data.frame in the context of this example?

Comment: I'd say yes. If you simply replace the function `data_frame()` by `data.frame()` (i.e. creating a data.frame instead of a tibble) you get warning messages

`In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character`

You should then use the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to avoid these (there are many articles on problems due to `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default).

Apart from that the tibble is nicer if you have more links: not the whole tibble is printed by default but only the first ten rows.